# How to get the String.xlm file in the second activity?

Tags: android

I have made a Song List using ArrayList, and I got all the information and it can be passed to the second activity and open it on a new page. What I want to have is when I click the song list of the song 1 or song 2, then it opens in a new page, and the new page shows the details and the image of the song 1 or 2. Also, I made the details and images of the song in the String.xml file.

```
@Override

final Song song1 = new Song("Love Story","Taylor Swift","September 12,2008", "$1.29");
Song song2 = new Song("Lover","Taylor Swift","August 23,2019", "$1.29" );
Song song3 = new Song("I Forgot That You Existed", "Taylor Swift", "August 23,2019", "$1.29");
Song song4 = new Song("The Archer", "Taylor Swift", "August 23,2019", "$1.29");
Song song5 = new Song("I Think He Knows","Taylor Swift", "August 23,2019", "$1.29");

final List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
songs.add(song1);
songs.add(song2);
songs.add(song3);
songs.add(song4);
songs.add(song5);

  MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, songs);
  listView_Main.setAdapter(adapter);

 listView_Main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

         Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),SongDetailActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("currentSong",(Serializable) songs.get(i));
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

But my problem is I don't how to get the String.xml file of the song to setText in the second activity.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_detail);

    textViewSongDetail=findViewById(R.id.textView_SongDetail);
    imageViewSongDetail=findViewById(R.id.image_SongDetail);

 Song currentSong=(Song)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("currentSong");

  textViewSongDetail.setText(R.string.loveStory_SongDetail);
  imageViewSongDetail.setImageResource(R.drable.love_story);

  textViewSongDetail.setText(currentSong.getSongName().indexOf(0));
  imageViewSongDetail.setImageResource(currentSong.getSongName().indexOf(0));

  textViewSongDetail.setText(currentSong.getSongName().indexOf(1));
  imageViewSongDetail.setImageResource(currentSong.getSongName().indexOf(1));
}
```

So, if I using textViewSongDetail.setText(R.string.loveStory_SongDetail); I can get the detail for the song and opened in the new page, but it was for all song lists when I clicked.

Then my problem is right here, textViewSongDetail.setText(currentSong.getSongName().indexOf(1));
 I don't know how to get the R.string.file to setText or images for the positions of song 1 or 2.

Comment: Maybe pass the resId into the intent of the activity, then pass that resId to setText?

Comment: getting the R.string should be the same if you handle `onCreate` in your second activity.  Try  instantiating a static `string` in  your second activity and then set it's value `onCreate` using something like `getResources().getString(R.string.loveStory_SongDetail);` .. if you couldn't use that method it was probably due to incorrect context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Song model should be like this:

```
public class Song implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String singer;
    private String release;
    private String price;
    private String description;
    private int imageId;

    public Song(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And create Song like below:

```
Song song1 = new Song("Love Story","Taylor Swift","September 12,2008", "$1.29", getString(R.string.song_description1),
R.drawable.song_image1);
```

And in second activity use like this:

```
textViewSongDetail.setText(currentSong.getSongDescription());

imageViewSongDetail.setImageResource(currentSong.getImageId());
```

Comment: I got it, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Store int resource I'd of the song in your song model and get the resource id in second a activity and pass it to getString(resId) to get the string.